# Estimating a new latitude/longitude using 2 previous datapoints and elapsed time: proofcheck help

Tags: kinematics, gps

I'm doing this all in code, could anyone with a better understanding of physics than mine read over my method to make sure my principle is sound? I have a device constantly sending a timestamp and it's GPS latitude/longitude to my server and I'm trying to use the two latest entries and time elapsed to give a very rough estimate of where it might be 'in between' updates:

[image]

*"so given it was at point x at this time, then point y at this time, 210 seconds have elapsed since it was at point y, assuming it just keeps going it should be at an estimated point z"*.- what I am trying to achieve.

*(the time is unix time, i.e seconds elapsed since Jan 01 1970 UTC)
Formula below:*

```
speedLat=(latitude-oldLatitude)/(timeSent-oldTimeSent)
speedLong=(longitude-oldLongitude)/(timeSent-oldTimeSent)
age=(currentUnixTime-timeSent)   
estimateNewLat=latitude+(age*speedLat)
estimateNewLong=longitude+(age*speedLong)
```

### WORKINGS (got the values from testing):

speedLat=([53.385360717773]-[53.3740234375])/([1551885285]-[1551877122])

```
      =1.3888619715102E-6
```

speedLong=([-6.6032276153564]-[-6.6032023429871])/([1551885285]-[1551877122])

```
       =-6.609086514045
```

age=(1892135)

estimateNewLat=latitude+(age*speedLat)

```
            =56.013684778518
```

estimateNewLong=longitude+(age*speedLong)

```
             =-6.609086514045
```

How does it look? Are the principles and units of measurement fine? If you're still with me thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation assumes Cartesian coordinates, but that's not the case for longitude and latitude, which are [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) (with the $r$ coordinate constant). The point is, the rate of change of latitude and longitude for a given speed *depends on where you are*.

On a spherical surface of radius $r = R$ with standard spherical coordinates $(\theta, \phi)$, the metric is given by: $$g_{ij} = \begin{bmatrix} R^2 & 0 \\ 0 & R^2 \sin^2 \theta \end{bmatrix}$$ and the velocity is given by $\mathbf{v} = R\dot{\theta} \mathbf{\hat{θ}} + R \sin \theta \dot{\phi} \mathbf{\hat{ϕ}}$, which you need to integrate to obtain the displacement. One possible method is to take readings across very small time steps in which you can assume that the coordinates are approximately Cartesian (which is to say that the metric remains constant) and recompute the metric after each time step.

Comment: Thank you for editing your answer with some extra clarity, I have virtually no physics background so that was very helpful. So if I understand correctly, the formula I am using is reasonably accurate over small distances? As the distance gets bigger, the direction should be roughly accurate but the rate of displacement will get increasingly inaccurate?

Comment: Yes, for your use case, there would be virtually no significant change in the metric, therefore you can essentially treat the system as Cartesian. However, you still need to scale the longitude by $\sin \theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle down from the North Pole. In other words, $\theta = \pi/2 - \text{latitude}$. In layman's terms, you need to account for the fact that it takes much less distance to transverse a given longitude near the poles than at the equator.